# Правильная организация файловой системы сайта визитки

Tags: веб-программирование, файлы

Как правильней организаовать файловую архитектуру сайта визитки?

так? -

```
/js
/img
/css
index.html
contacts.html
about.html
```

или так? -

```
/js
/img
/css
index.html
/about/index.html
/contacts/index.html
```

Не могу решить, какую надо использовать, может кто-то из Вас посоветует, объяснит.

Comment: Зависит от того, какие ссылки вы хотите видеть site.com/contact.html или site.com/contact/

Все остальное - безразлично, если б проект был крупный, ставили б ЦСМ.

Comment: Ваш сайт будет на чистом HTML+JS?

Comment: Да, на чистом HTML+CSS+JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для визитки вполне достаточно index.html со встроенными стилями, имхо...